# How to debug a Node.js app that take input from the command line?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am working on a node.js chat app that takes input from the `stdin` and sends output to `stdout`. Using it requires access to the console.

The problem is that launching the app in debug mode blocks the console. How can I debug (inspect objects when breakpoints are reached) while having access to `stdin` in the console?

Comment: I think you can simulate `stdin` and `stdout` inside your app by providing regular values and after debugging return them to original `stdin` and `stdout`

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure I follow. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Write a piece of your code which has `stdin` and `stdout`

Comment: @CrazyCoder is there any chance you can look into this issue?